# How to create page links?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know current user's location. It can be one of the following url:

```
(1) http://myapp.appspot.com/something/something-else/
(2) http://myapp.appspot.com/something/something-else
(3) http://myapp.appspot.com/something/something-else/page1
(4) http://myapp.appspot.com/something/something-else/page3
```

(actually, addresses 1, 2 and 3 are for the same page1)

I need to display on these pages link for page2:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/something/something-else/page2
```

The question is how to generate such link?

I've tried to use relative links: `/page2` and `page2` - doesn't work properly. I am not sure how to create absolute link with `self.request.path` - it doesn't work properly also.

Comment: please add more info... it's impossible to know what you want with your current description

Comment: @fceruti, what is exactly not clear here? I have user on current page (possible links are given above - actually urls (1), (2) and (3) are for the same page), I need to generate link for the second page.

Comment: @fceruti, I've rephrased my question. Please also see Drew's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`/page2` will never work; the leading / makes it relative to the website root rather than the current directory.

`page2` should work for everything except #2; without a trailing slash, `something-else` is interpreted as a file rather than the current directory.

One solution would be to link to `/something/something-else/page2` so your link doesn't change  based on the user's address.

Comment: Drew, you've described everything correctly :). My question is how to generate that page2 link? I.e. I need to take current url (see 4 options above), do some transformations and get link to page2. The question is about these transformations - what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`import something #refers to your .py file with the template handler`

...

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([

  ('/something/something-else/', something.SomeThingElseHandler),

  ('/something/something-else', something.SomeThingElseHandler),

  ('/something/something-else/'  + '([^/]+)/', something.PageHandler),
  #The above pattern will be recognized if you close the url with /
  #If you want your url to end without the slash your remove it for the reg ex. like
  ('/something/something-else/'  + '([^/]+)', something.PageHandler),      
],
debug=config.DEBUG)
```

util.run_wsgi_app(application)

In `something.py`, in your `class PageHandler` you have to parse the key or the id you are parsing manually to render the correct content.

Comment: Thanks, Chris-Top. This is what I already have. The question is different (sorry, looks like it was confusing in the beginning - I've just edited it).